# monacaのdatepickerの使い方を教えてください

Tags: html, monaca, cordova

[Datepickerプラグイン - Monacaドキュメント](http://docs.monaca.mobi/2.9/ja/reference/phonegap_plugin/datepicker/)

上記ページを参照して、monacaのCordovaプラグイン「datepicker」を有効にするところまではできました。

ただ、そのあと**実際どこに何を記述すればいいかわかりません。**
初歩的な質問で申し訳ないです・・

Androidの場合・iOS の場合と分かれているということは、
共通のindex.htmlに記述してもだめということかもしれません。

でも、Androidフォルダ・iOSフォルダ以下のどちらにもhtmlは生成されていないので、
どこに書けばいいかわかりません。

あと、できればこの問題が解決した後に「**今日の日付から指定された日付を引き算する**」という処理をしたいです。それについてもアドバイスいただけると嬉しいです。

お手数ですが、ご回答よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ドキュメントに書いているソースコードをindex.htmlにまずはそのまま貼り付けてみてはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: そのまま貼り付けでできました！アドバイスありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

index.htmlに記述すれば、大丈夫です。下記のようにmonaca.isAndroidやmonaca.isIosというプロパティを使ってOSごとに書き分けることができます。

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script>

      function dateTest() {

        if(monaca.isAndroid === true) {

            var myNewDate = new Date();

            window.plugins.datePicker.show({
                date : myNewDate,
                mode : 'date',
                allowOldDates : true
            }, function(returnDate) {
                var newDate = new Date(returnDate);
                alert(newDate.toString());
            });

        } else {
            var datePicker = window.plugins.datePicker;
            datePicker.show({
                "mode" : "datetime",
                "date" : new Date("2000/01/02 03:04:05")
            }, function(date){
                alert(new Date(date).toString())
            });
        }
    }    

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <br />
    <button onclick="dateTest()">Test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

> あと、できればこの問題が解決した後に「今日の日付から指定された日付を引き算する」という処理をしたいです。それについてもアドバイスいただけると嬉しいです

DateオブジェクトにはgetHours()など時間等を取得する関数がありますので、それらを組み合わせて実現できます。MDNが詳しいのでこちらを見てください。

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: お礼が遅くなって申し訳ありません。
詳しい回答ありがとうございます！
教えていただいたことを参考に、修正します！！